# How to return result set along with delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get the record from table `QUEUE` as well as delete the same record.

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.QUEUE 
( 
     QUEUEID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     SOMEACTION VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Through this query using `updlock` & `readpast` I am able to delete the record what already processed, but I need also that record as a result, how to do this?

I need both `QUEUEID` and `SOMEACTION` column in the result set.

```
BEGIN TRAN TRAN1  

SELECT TOP 1 @queueid = QUEUEID  
FROM DBO.QUEUE WITH (updlock, readpast)  

PRINT 'processing queueid # ' + CAST(@queueid AS VARCHAR)  

DELETE FROM DBO.QUEUE  
WHERE QUEUEID = @queueid 

COMMIT
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  A transaction seems appropriate here.

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx#CaptureResults)? `DELETE FROM DBO.QUEUE OUTPUT DELETED.QUEUEID, DELETED.SOMEACTION WHERE QUEUEID = @queueid`

Comment: Yes, and I think transaction is also not required

Comment: So if you read the manual and already know about the `OUTPUT` clause, why are you asking how to do it?

Comment: i didn't know about this OUTPUT DELETED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you and @Andreas already mentioned - use the `OUTPUT` clause with your `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM DBO.QUEUE  
OUTPUT deleted.QueueId, deleted.SomeAction
WHERE QUEUEID = @queueid
```

This will return (as a result set) the values that have been deleted.